# Why I am having ERROR on implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' when adding Firebase connection?

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

When I modify my build.gradle files to use the Firebase plugin, It shows me an error on implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

I have already added the google-services.json file into my Android app module root directory.

My error: 
Issue ID= Gradle compatible

> All com.android.support libraries must have the exact same version
>   specification...Found versions 28.0.0,26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and
>   com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0

I have tried to comment it out:

```
//noinspection GradleCompatible

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

But also it didn't work it cant communicate with firebase servers

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.tinder"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.9'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My build.gradle code(Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

I just expect to be able to connect my Firebase to my android app

Comment: include this one : implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'

Comment: Still having the same Error

Comment: what is your gradle version in gradle-wrapper.properties?

Comment: distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

Comment: try with removing 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.9' library. Because, buildToolsVersion for the library is "22.0.1".

Comment: i was getting the same error even before adding the swipecards library

Answer (score 4):

The solution is:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0' // NEED TO ADD
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0' //NEED TO ADD

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by changing the version of `Fire-base` and `classpath` dependencies.

The latest version of dependencies conflicted with `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` in App level `build.gradle`.

My changes are given below

- `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'` to `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'` in App level `build.gradle` file.
- `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'` to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'` in Project level `build.gradle` file.

*** If you migrate your project to AndroidX, then you will be able to use all the latest dependencies without facing this kind of errors ***